# How to read multidimensional HashMap using key as String

Tags: java, android

I created multi dimensional array using hashmap. How to read value of 2nd array using key which is a String. I read on other articles it say using keyset and iterator but never show how to read specific value using String key.

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Example array (structure only):

```
myMap[1]["title"] = "test";
```

I can read this:

```
myMap.get(1);
```

But i cant read this:

```
myMap.get(1).get("title");
```

I also tried but failed:

```
HashMap<String, String> subHash = myMap.get(position);
subHash.get("title");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the failure? Are you getting an error? the wrong result?

Comment: Can you show the context where you instantiate and add things to the map? Since the double gets should work. You can also try to loop through the maps and print all the content to see if the value exist somewhere in the nested map.

Comment: `["title"]` you cannot index into arrays using strings in Java. You can only index into an array using its integer indices.

Comment: @Michael i assume thats pseudo code to show what he wants to retrieve.

Comment: One a side note it would be nicer and more according to the convetnions  if you instantiate the map like this:  `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Sorry guys, i think i found the mistake was in my "myMap". My first key was starting 1. Supposed to start from 0. This method works: myMap.get(0).get("title"); I was reading from onBindViewHolder from my RecyclerView class